# How to remove motion time numbers of clock with String type in Swift?

Tags: string, animation, time, swift3, label

I've code to show clock time with the `timeLabel:UILabel` in my app whit **Swift3**.

And that is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.currentTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func currentTime(){
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    if second % 2 == 0{
        timeLabel.text = "\(hour):\(minutes)"
    }else {
        timeLabel.text = "\(hour) \(minutes)"
    }
```

But when two points disappear between hour and minutes numbers, they are a little bit movement. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a trick  can be fix that.

By adding another label with same background color in `else` condition, Yup

For **Swift 3:**

```
var attributes = [String: AnyObject]()
attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = self.view.backgroundColor

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: ":", attributes: attributes)

label.attributedText = attributedString
```